# How to handle "HTTP error 502" in python?

Tags: python, exception, python-requests, try-catch, urlimageviewhelper

I,m trying to handle "HTTP ERROR 502" which is coming from reddit api service since its exceeding its Limit

So I'm trying to reconnect it by following code snippet:

```
import urllib
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import URLError, HTTPError
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

try:
    with urllib3.request.urlopen(submission.url) as url:
        arr = np.asarray(bytearray(url.read()), dtype=np.uint8)
        rgb_img = cv2.imdecode(arr, -1) 
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join('image_data',str(unique_name)+".jpg"),rgb_img)

except HTTPError as e:
    if e.code == 502:

        @retry(urllib.URLError, tries=4, delay=3, backoff=2)
         def urlopen_with_retry():
             return urllib.urlopen(submission.url)

          urlopen_with_retry()

    else:                    
        print ('Failure: ' + str(e.reason))
```

But this is not working and its giving error that "retry" is not a found in  **urlib**

How to properly handle this HTTP 500 ish errors ?

Comment: Your problem is `"retry" is not a part of urlib`, not the error code (you'd get the same problem for any other error code).

Comment: you need to define `retry` or `import` it. Check [this](https://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/11/trying-out-retry-decorator-python/)